# Make jQuery click on a button when someone has confirmed (dialog box)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a wordpress auction site and wanted to add a confirm dialog with jquery when someone clicks on the "bid" button. I can achieve this with the default system dialog but I want a more custom dialog box with jQuery. How can I make it click the bid button once the end user has confirmed the bid?

Here is the code example:

```
            <button type="submit" class="bid_button button alt"><?php echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'bid_text', esc_html__( 'Bid', 'auctions-for-woocommerce' ), $product ) ); ?></button>
            <script>
                jQuery('button').confirm({
                    title: 'titletext',
                    content: 'content text"',
                    type: 'red',
                    buttons: {   
                        ok: {
                            text: "OK",
                            btnClass: 'btn-primary',
                            keys: ['enter'],
                            action: function(){
                                 console.log('Brukeren bekreftet "OK"');
                            }
                        },
                        No: function(){
                                text: "No",
                                jQuery.alert('Kansellert!');
                                console.log('the user clicked cancel');
                        }
                    }
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: you can trigger a click on the `bid_button` with `$('.bid_button').click()`, does this answer your question?

Comment: Yeah that works, but the dialog goes in loop, how do I prevent this?

Comment: the thing what you are now doing is confirming the submit button and force it again to open the dialog, what exactly you want to reach with the automatic button press?

Comment: maybe you can provide a working js fiddle code with example code?

Comment: I'm not familiar with coding at all, so I'm not able to provide this info, the bid button places a new bid on click. All I know it works with onclick="clicked(event)     <script>
     function clicked(e)
     {
      if(!confirm('Vennligst bekreft ditt bud.'))e.preventDefault();
     }
    </script> Can I dig up some more info the noob way?

Comment: should your form be submitted after confirming the dialog? or what you expect to happen?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I need, submit after confirm. thanks for asking the right questions..

Comment: can you try to put this `submitForm: true,` right after  `type: 'red',`?

Comment: also add `post: true` so its not a get form submit

Comment: Added both lines in this order: post: true, submitForm: true, type: 'red', - with same result, it's not submitting. I also tried without $('.bid_button').click() - same result just without the loop

Comment: can you provide us the full HTML code from your form which should be submitted in your question?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/peterq1/6sxrtgpy/

Comment: Here is how you prevent the loop. https://mauricius.dev/confirm-form-submission-without-loops-using-jquery/ or make a counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like this libary is not created for submitting forms via button, more like using it for  `<a>` tags, source - https://github.com/craftpip/jquery-confirm/issues/229

I thought i will give you still a way to solve your problem.
now i am preventing the default behavior from the button when its not confirmed and trigger it again when its confirmed, but this time the button can submit the form.
Also added the id `submitButton` to your button for making it individual.

`<button type="submit" id="submitButton" class="bid_button button alt"></button>`

```
<script>
   var confirmed = false;
   $('#submitButton').on('click', function() {
     if (!confirmed) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $.confirm({
         title: 'titletext ',
         content: 'content text"',
         type: 'red',
         buttons: {
           ok: {
             text: "OK",
             btnClass: 'btn-primary',
             keys: ['enter'],
             action: function() {
               confirmed = true;
               $('#submitButton').click()
               console.log('Brukeren bekreftet "OK"');
             }
           },
           No: function() {
             text: "No",
             jQuery.alert('Kansellert!');
             console.log('the user clicked cancel');
           }
         }
       })
     } else {
       confirmed = false
     }
   })
</script>
```

hope I could help you. :)

Comment: Appreciate all the help I can get. With this code I get an Syntax error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" - any idea?

Comment: by the way, I'm using this https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/

Comment: updated my code, now it should work. oh okay i thought you are using the other one, libarys with same names ough. Maybe i can have a look at it later.